# Is using magic methods quicker than using operator in python?

Tags: python, operators, magic-methods

I want to ask that is using magic methods( like `int.__add__()`) is quicker than using operators (like `+`) ?

will it make a difference even by a bit?

thanks.

Comment: No, because the compiler should generate the same byte code.

Comment: @Barmar
not even by a bit, I mean if calling the method directly so that the compiler don't have to, should make a difference ( atleast a very very small difference)?

Comment: Why don't you just look at the generated code?

Comment: If it's quicker, it's not quick enough to make up for the loss of readability. Don't call magic methods explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the disassembled byte code for 3 different ways of adding.

```
import dis

def add1(a, b):
    return a + b

dis.dis(add1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE

def add2(a, b):
    return a.__add__(b)

dis.dis(add2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__add__)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 RETURN_VALUE

def add3(a, b):
    return int.__add__(a, b)

dis.dis(add3)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__add__)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

`a+b` generates the simplest byte code, but I expect that the interpreter's code for `BINARY_ADD` simply calls the first arguments's `__add__()` method, so it's effectively the same as `a.__add__(b)`.

`int.__add__(a, b)` looks like it might be faster because it doesn't have to find the method for a specific object, but looking up the `int.__add__` attribute may be just as expensive.

If you really want to find out which is best, I suggest you run benchmarks.